# GetComponent(Type customType) behaving differently than GetComponent<customType>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this method 'SetStats' that's part of a class.

```
public class HeroUnit: MonoBehaviour {
    public virtual void SetStats(Stats stats) => Stats = stats;
}
```

When I instantiate a gameObject by pointing to a prefab, then get the component of a known type 'HeroUnit' attached to it, I can call the SetStats method without any problem.

```
void SpawnUnit(Vector3 pos) {
    var spawnedGameObject = Instantiate(unitPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity,transform) as GameObject; 
    var spawned = spawnedGameObject.GetComponent<HeroUnit>();

    spawned.SetStats(stats);
}
```

However, when I don't force a known component type, and that I rather give it dynamically to the GetComponent() method: the instantiation works, but I can't call the SetStats method anymore.

```
void SpawnUnit(String myUnit, Vector3 pos) {
    var spawnedGameObject = Instantiate(unitPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity,transform) as GameObject; 
    Type unitType = Type.GetType(myUnit);
    var spawned = spawnedGameObject.GetComponent(unitType);

    spawned.SetStats(stats);
}
```

This returns the following compile error :

**error CS1061: 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'SetStats' and no accessible extension method 'SetStats' accepting a first argument of type 'Component' could be found**

Any idea how to make the compiler understand that 'spawned' is not a 'Component' when the code is ran? I checked 'spawned' type at runtime, and it is a 'HeroUnit', as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `var` off and see if it'll compile. I don't think you're getting a `HeroUnit`, I think you're getting a `Component`.

Try casting the result of GetComponent, like

```
HeroUnit spawned = (HeroUnit) spawnedGameObject.GetComponent(unitType);
```

I'll say too that passing types around as strings is a bad idea. You got the string from somewhere, so just use the types instead of strings.

You're probably going to come back and complain about that your unitType isn't necessarily a HeroUnit, to which I would reply, "then how do you know it has a `SetStats` method?"

You might be better off casting to a base class or interface, but again this string business is not helping you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chuck!

The following calls all return the same type when I call "spawned.GetType()", which is "HeroUnit". Only the last one can't call the 'SetStats' method :

- var spawned = spawnedGameObject.GetComponent<HeroUnit>(); ///
- HeroUnit spawned = (HeroUnit)spawnedGameObject.GetComponent(unitType); ///
- var spawned = spawnedGameObject.GetComponent(unitType);

I can indeed call 'SetStats' when I cast 'spawned' as a 'HeroUnit', but you're right about it not really solving my problem.
I guess I'll find a way other than passing it with a string...

Comment: I did what you say and made all my 'Units' inherit from a base class which has the 'SetStats' method.
Then  I called it this way, which seems to work. Cheers! ===> UnitBase spawned2 = (UnitBase)spawnedGameObject.GetComponent(unitType);